# PHP simple HTML DOM parser not work

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I have this problem

**This it works:**

```
foreach($inzeraty->find("a") as $nazov)
    { 
      echo $nazov."<br />"; 
    }
```

but I need just first tag `"a"` and this **NOT work:**

```
foreach($inzeraty->find("a", 0) as $nazov)
    { 
      echo $nazov."<br />"; 
    }
```

> Error:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: If you only need a single `a` then why use a `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
$first_anchor = $inzeraty->find("a", 0);
echo $first_anchor;
```

From the docs: 
**// Find (N)th anchor, returns element object or null if not found (zero based)**
It returns one only element, not an array, so you cannot loop over it.

Answer (score 0):

Treat it as an array, `echo $inzeraty->find("a")[0];`

Answer (score -1):

i will suggest to count and display the first. as the following:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($inzeraty->find("a") as $nazov)
{ 
  $i++;
  if($i == 1)
    echo $nazov."<br />"; 
}
```